# Http response is getting trimmed

Tags: http, get, jersey

I made one http get call using jersey framework. The response is supposed to be a json map. However the response is not complete. Somehow complete data is not reaching. Any suggestion?

```
responseString = target.request()
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
System.out.println(" Obtained responseString is "+responseString);
```

Comment: Show an example of response you are waiting and getting. Could be due to some characters in JSON...

Comment: I don't think that should be the issue. All the characters which appeared are jut normal alphanumeric characters